# PHP Mobile detect to work with APC + W3 total cache + Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, mobile, apc

I'm trying to get this PHP lightweight mobile detect (https://github.com/serbanghita/Mobile-Detect ) to work with our install based on Wordpress + W3 Total Cache and APC.

However, the object cache caches the Mobile_Detect.php file and it will eventually just work for the first visitor on any site, after that the information is cached and it doesn't work.

Will it be enough for me to specify the apc.filters to Mobile_Detect.php to get this to work? Or is there something else to take into concideration?

```
<?php
    include 'mobile-detect/Mobile_Detect.php';
    $detect = new Mobile_Detect();
    ?>

    <?php
        if ($detect->isMobile()) { ?>
        <!-- do some mobile stuff -->
    <?php } else { ?><!-- do something else --><?php } ?>
```

Comment: Did you find the solution for this problem? I'm having the exact same issue.

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for us was to reject mobile user agents from caching.

Go to **Performance/Page Cache** and in the advanced section, fill the textbox labeled «Rejected user agents:» with the names of the user agents you want to reject. ([yourWpSite]**/wp-admin/admin.php?page=w3tc_pgcache#advanced**)

if you have doubts about the user agent names, check **Performance/User Agent Groups**. By default it's loaded with 2 lists, the first is for mobile user agents.

Comment: great dude.. helped me